# burnt out due to toxic env and culture

Tags: bullying, burnout

I am a software engineer and I inherited and started to own a project after teams re-org.  While I have worked on some parts of the project, I don't know 100%. Even before the teams re-org, my teammates have been secretive and withholding information that is useful for me to do my job.  The features that were done were in bad quality or not usable.

For example, they wrote a beautiful blog (they had removed the content, only the title remain) about how the project benefits from automated testing, but the automated testing is just a postman script and does not work at all.

Due to the bad quality of the product, it had a lot of issues and it took a long time to deliver any features. In my performance review, I was marked at a bottom performer and likely to be fired.

My questions are:

1. Mental health - this is a hard bullet to swallow and I am burnt out - advice for moving forward; I owned I played some parts in this too.
2. Work - I have decided to look for a new job, which might take a while due to my burn out, but I still have to maintain and deliver features, how can I point out that the bad quality is the reason.  Note that the original authors are very powerful in my org.

Comment: Sorry for the issues you are facing. Do you have a particular question that we can help you with ?

Answer (score 3):

> Mental health - this is a hard bullet to swallow and I am burn out - advice for moving forward; I owned I played some parts in this too.

Go see a doctor. Even a general practitioner will be able to guide you to a specialist that can help you. This is not something you shake off on your own.

If you had chopped an axe into your leg due to bad practices at work, you would scoff if someone suggested you just sleep it off and get another job as a woodchuck. Go get professional help.

> Work - I have decided to look for a new job, which might take a while due to my burn out, but I still have to maintain and deliver features, how can I point the bad quality is the reason. Note that the original authors are very powerful in my org

Don't. Don't bother. It will not help anyway. They have decided that you do bad work, every single word you say from now on will be seen as an excuse.

Work normally. If you cannot make a deadline, communicate that. If you have the power to do that, set less stressful deadlines. They have already decided how to view you, there is nothing to gain from further engagement. Don't get fired while you job search, but otherwise, treat it like it is: just a job to make you money while you job search.

When you job search, make sure you find a company that values all those things: a good team, work life balance, good code quality, good management. They exist. If you jump off into just the first job offer you get, chances are you will end up in the same situation again.

In my experience, companies that have an actual *owner* are way better in that regard, because an owner is in it for the long run. A CEO who is just driven by getting their next bonus from a board and better job at another company, who is looking for career advancement, doesn't plan to be around in 3 years and so they aren't interested in anything that might be good for the company in 3 years. Investors don't care for long term growth, they will invest their money somewhere else, if this company only produces crap long term. But someone who owns the company is very much interested that the company grows and prospers and they are not looking for career opportunities at all costs, they are already the top honcho. On average, they might be more interested in quality than cheap immediate gains.

But that is just on average. Make sure you get a good feel for the company, asks questions in the interview, make sure your next company is better than this.

Comment: I would upvote it but for one issue, nowhere OP mentions work life balance issues, not even eludes to needing to do long hours etc, and this seems so central to the answer.

Comment: I'm not sure how it is central to the answer, when I only mentioned it once as part of an enumeration what makes a good workplace/company. But yes, I just assumed it's not good there, since I have never met someone with burnout, who had a great work-life balance. You cannot have a great work-life-balance, if one part of that balance is literally making you sick. Not bringing stress home is part of what I would call work-life-balance and a burnout is the definition of bringing stress home.

Comment: My contention out of that is the same as where our answers disagree - I don't see the practices op described as being anything but industry standard. I am also not denying ops burnout issues, it's how they feel, should see a doctor, but in all likelihood their next job will be more of the same. So core of the issue needs addressing - why working with non-perfect code drives them to it.  It's honestly a problem I see with mostly younger developers a lot, that needing to adjust to reality of day to day software dev can be rough, this sounds extremely similar.

Comment: @AidaPaul Well, I guess we are just living in different parts of the world. In western countries with sensible labor laws and employee protections, while I can see that happening as an outlier and "that really bad place I once worked at", I think it's not industry standard. In other places around the world, it well might be. I cannot tell you you are wrong, I have no idea what the industry standard is where you live, it certainly is not that bleak where I live.

Comment: Sorry, what is the industry standard about quality of code and documentation? No idea how any of this violates any protections that OP struggles with the code, or can't get docs. I think you are taking more from OPs post that OP told us, doesn't mean it's wrong, but we just don't have that data, or even hint that any labor laws were violated.

Comment: I don't know why you keep picking a single word out of enumerations and paragraphs and focus on that ignoring all context. I never said any labor laws were violated. People are stronger and less prone to abuse if they have rights. Not a novel concept.

Comment: The industry standard where I live is that you don't work alone without help or documentation. Software is developed in teams, meaning helpful colleagues, not secretive opponents. The toxic dumpster fire the OP describes is possible, as all kind of bad working conditions are in a poorly managed, bad company, but they are notable exceptions to the industry standard. Again, I cannot claim to know what happens in your part of the world. If it is different for you, that is sad. I wish it were better. But your bleak description does not resonate with my reality.

Answer (score 2):

Preface: there are exceptions to the below, I know, but based on my experience of working with dozens of companies over 24 years, they are very rare.

> how can I point the bad quality is the reason

What that says to pretty much most bosses/managers is: "This is too hard for me too solve".

Working with bad, untested, barely working code with no documentation is software development 101. It's the daily bread. It's par for the course. It's normal. I say this many times as it's important for that to sink in, as this will be the situation almost everywhere you will go, from tiny companies to massive enterprises.

Do you know why? Because software that's neat, documented, and tested is rarely delivering the business features in the timing the business needs them to happen. Making code nice is expensive, and has high missed opportunity cost due to late delivery where time is of the essence, more than future maintenance costs.

So if your entire issue is that the code base is a bit of a mess, there's no docs, tests etc - your next job is going to be likely very much the same. If dredging awful code is not your thing, and causes you to burn out, you may want to seek an alternative career, as you will need to learn how to deliver in that environment.

So keep that in mind when job hunting. But also don't throw out baby with the bathwater, you were not fired yet, so unless you have another job lined up (or substantial savings to weather the storm, as market is VERY saturated with competitive developers right now), consider taking a deep breath and fighting for your job. How to start that, that's a great another question!

Comment: " If dredging awful code is not your thing, and causes you to burn out, you may want to seek an alternative career" Why would you do that? Either change your current employers practices, or move on to one that produces quality instead of cheap quantity. There is nothing special about software, every industry has their quality products and their cheap crappy "others".

Comment: @nvoigt you are confusing bad code with a bad product (and really, what makes bad code). Many of the most successful software companies in the world are underpinned by ugliest code ever seen to the light of the day (and it's not bad code, sure it's ugly, but it does exactly what's needed). So unless your product is directly the code, and it was required to specific standard, that's not the product.